# Joomla 3.3: Get data from column 'attribs' in the table 'content'

Tags: plugins, joomla

I'm using the Aixeena Easy CCK-plugin in my Joomla 3.3-website. It's a plugin that allows me to add custom fields in my Article Edit-page. The content I fill out there (should) show up on my website. The plugin stores his information in the #_content table in the attribs column.

On their website, Aixeena says that I have to use the following code to make the filled out text visible on my website:

```
$attrb = json_decode($this->item->attribs); 
echo $attrb->fieldname;
```

This code drops the following error:

> **Notice:** Undefined property: JDocumentHTML::$item in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/buutpot/templates/buutpot.nl-standaardtemplate/index.php on line 123
>
> **Notice:** Trying to get property of non-object in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/buutpot/templates/buutpot.nl-standaardtemplate/index.php on line 123
>
> **Fatal error:** Call to a member function get() on a non-object in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/buutpot/templates/buutpot.nl-standaardtemplate/index.php on line 124

I think it is written for an older version of Joomla. Then I searched around and found this code:

```
$params  = $this->item->params;
echo $params->get('fieldname');
```

When I use this code on my site, it gives me the following error's:

> **Notice:** Undefined property: JDocumentHTML::$item in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/buutpot/templates/buutpot.nl-standaardtemplate/index.php on line 123
>
> **Notice:** Trying to get property of non-object in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/buutpot/templates/buutpot.nl-standaardtemplate/index.php on line 123
>
> **Notice:** Trying to get property of non-object in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/buutpot/templates/buutpot.nl-standaardtemplate/index.php on line 124

That's without a fatal error. I'm not sure why it is without.

Could anybody help me out getting the right code to get my variable out of the table? Thanks in advance!

EDIT 1: Link to the plugin: http://www.aixeena.org/aixeena-lab/aixeena-easy-cck

EDIT 2: Edited my question in reply on the comment of Elin.

Comment: When you say "doesn't work" you need to be much more specific.  Is it throwing an error? (You have error reporting on development right?) Is it just echoing blank? The way I would debug is to first dump out $attrb and see if fieldname is really there as a property.

Comment: Unfortunately not...

Answer (score 0):

So like the notices say, the problem is that `$this->item` does not exist. You need to figure out what the actual name of the object is and use that rather than $this->item.  You will probably do that by looking in the layout of whereever it is that you are trying to display.  Can you please check your template to see if it has a layout override for the article view (assuming that is the view you are trying to access the form from)?

Comment: No, it does not have a template override. I've made the template myself using a blank template from [link](http://www.blank.vc). I'm trying to show the data in the index.php-file of my template. The variable `$params` is declared as `JFactory::getApplication()->getParams();`. `$this` is **not** declared in my index.php-file.

Comment: No you never pot this in the index.php file of our template! This belongs in the layout file for the view.  You have to think about the order that things happen in. The template index is processed before the view, so you do not yet have $this->item available (and often you wil not have $this->item) at all.

Answer (score 0):

I used this code to do a query on the database:

```
$db = JFactory::getDbo();
$query = $db->getQuery(true);
$query->select('attribs');
$query->from($db->quoteName('#__content'));
$query->where($db->quoteName('id')." = ".JRequest::getInt('id'));

$db->setQuery($query);
$attribs = $db->loadResult();
$attribs = json_decode($attribs, 'true');

$firstattr = $attribs['firstattr'];
$secondattr = $attribs['secondattr'];
$thirdattr = $attribs['thirdattr'];
$fourthattr = $attribs['fourthattr'];
```

But I'm sure this can be done simpler.

Answer (score 0):

```
$attribs = new JRegistry($article->attribs);
echo $fieldname = $attribs['fieldname'];
```

For example, I use this code in on ContentPrepare like this

```
function onContentPrepare($context, &$article, &$params, $page) {

        $attribs = new JRegistry($article->attribs);
        //url is my custom field for the content
        $url = $attribs['url'];
        ......
```